# Механизм сохранения данных с синхронизацией в приложении UWP

Tags: база-данных, sqlite, uwp

Какой механизм использовать для сохранения данных в приложении UWP, чтобы была возможность синхронизировать данные между устройствами?

Возможно идеальным решением является SQL Azure Database, но очевидно необходимо всегда иметь подключение к облачной базе данных.
Если рассматривать SQLite в качестве локального хранилища, то какой механизм/алгоритм использовать для периодической синхронизации?

Возможно кто то находил пример на GitHub'е, Code.MSDN.microsoft.com, CodePlex и др?

Answer (score 1):

Если вы рассматриваете Azure в качестве хранилища, то хорошим вариантом можно считать Azure Mobile Apps, которые позволяют синхронизировать облачную базу данных с локальной SQLite:
 [Приложение Windows 10 с данными в облаке с помощью Azure Mobile Apps](https://habrahabr.ru/post/277567/)
(смотрите по ссылке пункт Синхронизация с локальной базой SQLite)